# How does the namespace scope works in C++?

Tags: c++, namespaces, language-lawyer

C++ ISO draft 2020(6.4.6 Namespace Scope) quotes in the first paragraph(bolded by me):

> The declarative region of a namespace-definition is its namespace-body
> . Entities declared in a namespace-body are said to be members of the
> namespace, and names introduced by these declarations into the
> declarative region of the namespace are said to be member names of the
> namespace. A namespace member name has namespace scope. **Its potential
> scope includes its namespace from the name’s point of declaration
> (6.4.2) onwards**; and for each using-directive (9.8.3) that nominates
> the member’s namespace, the member’s potential scope includes that
> portion of the potential scope of the using-directive that follows the
> member’s point of declaration.

I thought it wouldn't have a difference between unnamed and named namespace, but the following code has problems:

```
#include <iostream>
namespace A {int a = 1;}
namespace {int b = 1;}
void main() {
    std::cout << a; // identifier "a" is undefined
    std::cout << b;
}
```

[Cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope) gives the reason for this problem:

> The potential scope of a name declared in an unnamed namespace or in
> an inline namespace includes the potential scope that name would have
> if it were declared in the enclosing namespace.

But based on my understanding of the first quote of this question, this error shouldn't occur. What happened here?

Comment: `namespace { /*body*/ }` behaves, [by definition](https://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.unnamed), as `namespace UniqueName {} using namespace UniqueName; namespace UniqueName { /*body*/ }` where `UniqueName` is some invented identifier unique to the translation unit. The difference between the two namespaces in your example is this implicit `using` directive.

Comment: If in your example `a` could be found by unqualified lookup, without specifying its namespace, namespaces would have been rather pointless. Why do you believe the error shouldn't occur? How do you arrive at this conclusion from the passage you quote?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I think the problem was my interpretation of the "onwards" word. I understood it as from the point of declaration, until (well, until everything) to the end of the translation unit, but the onward is until the end of the namespace body, right?

Comment: Plus I assumed that unnamed spaces would behave equal to named, I didn't have seen this implicit directive. And there is the following example in the draft that made me mix everything:

`namespace { int l=1; }// the potential scope of l is from its point of declaration to the end of the translation unit`

Comment: "includes **its namespace** from the point of declaration onwards". Not the whole source file onwards, but the parts of it that lie within the namespace it's a member of. "End of namespace body" is not well-defined, as a namespace may be defined in bits and pieces: `namespace N { int x;}  namespace N {int y;}`

Comment: The reason names declared in unnamed namespaces are visible in the enclosing namespace is the aforementioned implicit using directive. So the other part of your quote comes into play: "and for each using-directive (9.8.3) that nominates the member’s namespace, the member’s potential scope includes that portion of the potential scope of the using-directive..."

Answer (score 1):

> *I thought it wouldn't have a difference between unnamed and named namespace*

Both `a` and `b` are available in `main`. But `a` cannot be accessed without scope resolution. The documentation refers to "potential scope", "actual scope", and "scope", plus block/class/function/namespace scope, it can get confusing.

You can see the similarity of named and un-named `namespace` with this code:

```
class foo
{
    std::string str;
public:
    foo(const char* s) { str = s; cout << str << " foo()\n"; }
    ~foo() { cout << str << " ~foo()\n"; }
};

namespace named { foo a("named"); }
namespace { foo b("unnamed"); }
int main()
{
    cout << "start\n";
    named::a;
    b;
    cout << "end\n";
    return 0;
}
```